# I'm trying to create a logistic regression model for a spam email dataset but have a lot of variables (over 2500)(NOVICE)

Tags: r, classification, logistic-regression

As said above I'm trying to create a model for detecting spam emails based on word occurrences. my information from my dataset is as follows:

- about 2800 variables representing each word and the frequency of their occurrences
- binary spam variable 1 for spam 0 for legit

I've been using online resources but can only find logistic regression and NN tutorials for much smaller datasets, which seem much simpler in comparison. So far I've totaled up the total words for spam and non spam to analyze, but I'm having trouble creating the model itself

Does anyone have any sources or insight on how to manage this with a much larger dataset?

Apologies for the simple question (if it is so) I appreciate any advice.

Comment: I've managed to create a glm function with the spam variable and . for all of the variables, I imagine it's going to take a while though. I will see how far I can get with this method. Thanks for the point in the right direction guys!

Answer (score 1):

A classical approach uses a generalised linear model (GLM) with a penalty for the number of variables. The GLM will be the logistic regression model in this case. The classic approach for the penalty is the LASSO, ridge regression and elastic net techniques. The shrinkage in your parameter values may be such that no parameters are selected to be predictive if your ratio of the number of variables (p) to the number of samples (N) is too high. Some parameters can control the shrinkage for that. It's overall a well studied topic. Your questions haven't asked about the programming language you will use, but you may find helpful packages in Python, R, Julia and other widespread data science programming languages. There will also be a lot of information in the CV community.

Comment: I'd second this approach. The tags suggest R programming language - if so, the `glmnet` package is good and has nice tutorials available.

Comment: Sorry, yes I'm using R. I've been tasked with creating the model but I'm totally lost. I feel I would be better of with Python, but the language has been specified. I will try to find a video guide to walk through the process. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I would start analysing each variable individually. I would implement a logistic regression for each one, and remain only with those whose p-value is really significative.

After this first step, then you can run a more complex logistic regression model, where you include the remaining variables in the first step.